# What's the difference between class() and class

Tags: python, oop

So I'm trying out PySide, at the beginning when I tried to use:

`t = test()`

It would give me:
`TypeError: trybutton() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`

but by accident I saw that it would run just fine if I instead did:

`t = test`

So I'm wondering how that can be?

```
class test():

def trybutton(name, self):
    return QPushButton(name, self)

class main(QMainWindow):

        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            super(main, self).__init__(parent)
            self.testui()

        def testui(self):
            main.set_button(self, "test", "testy")

        def set_button(self, *names):
            t = test
            b = [t.trybutton(name, self) for name in names]

if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        frame = main()
        frame.show()
        app.exec_()
```

Comment: with `()` you are initializing an object instance of class `test`, whereas `t=test` is just reassigning the class `test` to a local variable `t` . You have to create an object instancd later on with `t()`

Comment: `def trybutton(name, self):` looks weird to me. self is supposed to be the first argument to a method, since it's supplied automatically by Python. That also explains your TypeError. `trybutton` takes two arguments, but you only need to supply one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`trybutton` is a class method and should not be called from an instantiated object

When an instantiated object calls one of his methods it always sends itself as the first argument 
so when you do `t=test()` 
and then `t.trybutton(a, b)` 
the method itself will receive 3 parameters (the_object, a, b) and thus the error `takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`

Answer (score 0):

Let's go over what happens in each case.

```
# Assign the class test to the variable t
t = test
# Call the method on the class, passing in two arguments explicitly.
b = [t.trybutton(name, self) for name in names]


# Create an object of the class test and assign it to the variable t
t = test()
# Call the method on the class, passing in two arguments explicitly, and one argument implicitly
# Note that the implicit argument is the argument t itself, which is passed as the first argument
b = [t.trybutton(name, self) for name in names]
```

That is why you are getting an error about passing `3` arguments when `2` are expected.

---

Here is one possible fix.

```
class test():
   def trybutton(self, name):
        return QPushButton(name, self)

t = test()
# pass one argument explicitly, one implicitly.
b = [t.trybutton(name) for name in names]
```

Comment: The first part of your answer and the fix still contain one of the OP's mistakes, the wrong argument order in `name, self`.

Comment: @lukasgraf, I checked the api and it looks like that method is in that order unless I misread the documentation.

Comment: you're totally right. Never mind my comment please, I was assuming the `def trybutton(name, self):` referred to a method definition, when in fact its a factory for `QPushButton`s.